# Force to downgrade API from 26.1 to 25.4

Tags: java, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I started a project with API 26. After some time I decided that I want to go with API 25, thus I replaced `compileSdkVersion`, `targetSdkVersion` and `minSdkVersion` 26->25. However, I keep getting error upon gradle sync/build saying:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
>   Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value value=(25.4.0) from [com.android.support:design:25.4.0] AndroidManifest.xml:28:13-35
>       is also present at [com.android.support:support-core-utils:26.1.0] AndroidManifest.xml:28:13-35 value=(26.1.0).
>       Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:26:9-28:38 to override.

At first I saw that some "External Libraries" (such as core-utils) still point to 26.1.0 so I tried to force using 25.4.0 in build.gradle file but it still links 26.1 as you can see on the screenshot below. What should I do to force downgrade to 25.4.0?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When i encounter similar issues I perform two actions to pin point the problem;

1. Use `./gradlew <module_name>:dependencies` to map out what is being transitively resolved to the unexpected support library version.
2. And armed with this information head on over to the module (looks like you only have 1 gradle module in your project) and then within that module's `build.gradle` explicitly define a `resolutionStrategy` such as;

Snippet;

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.force "com.android.support:support-core-utils:{version}"
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Your solution worked! However, I couldn't see any dependencies when running this command. The output was 
> Task :dependencies
------------------------------------------------------------
Root project
------------------------------------------------------------
No configurations
BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 2s

Comment: Sorry @Mike - it should read; ````./gradlew <module_name>:dependencies```` so in your case ````./gradlew app:dependencies````